# compile libc++ for ios?

Tags: ios, clang, libstdc++, libc++

I'd like to use `libclang` in my ios app for syntax highlighting.

I've cross-compiled clang for ios (armv7) and i'm able to use it for tokenize, diagnostics, etc. But when i try to tokenize/get diagnostics for .cpp file which have `#include <stdio.h>` or `iostream` or `cstdio.h` libclang outputs fatal diagnostics that header file is not found.

Do i have to cross-compile [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/), upload cross compiled headers and static lib to device and add according `-I` to libclang command-line arguments?

Comment: I guess it should be enough to configure the headers for armv7, since you don't need to link

Comment: i'm having header search error so it seems it needs path for them. Can i just copy headers files from iOS SDK folder to the iOS device and add -I?

Comment: using `-I` should work. You could also configure your compiler so that the search path is included by default, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I've copied headers from libcxx/include to device and added -I with headers path. Now for file which uses `#include <iostream>` i'm getting clang crash with the next error output: `Assertion failed: (Capacity - Index == TypeLoc::getFullDataSizeForType(T) && "incorrect data size provided to CreateTypeSourceInfo!"), function pushImpl, file /Users/asmirnov/Documents/dev/src/llvm_34_ios/tools/clang/lib/Sema/TypeLocBuilder.cpp, line 133.` It seems smth is wrong with headers and it hurts clang a lot

Comment: BTW cstdio header file from libcxx include folder (http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/cstdio) has `#include <stdio.h>` (line 100) and there is no stdio.h file in libcxx headers folder. This is misleading and i'm getting libclang diagnostics - fatal error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libc++ already exists on iOS.  You don't need to do anything special to access it.  Just link against /usr/lib/libc++.dylib in the iOS SDK.